# Average of sum and Sum of average of 2 random non zero distributions of numbers

Tags: means

Suppose we have

$$A_i \sim N( \mu_a, \sigma_a)$$
$$B_i \sim N( \mu_b, \sigma_b)$$

Where $A_i$ and $B_i$ are i.i.d. respectively, where $i = 1 \ldots n$, 
We are interested in
$$\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{ \frac{A_i}{ B_i} }  }{n} $$
and
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{A_i} }{  \sum_{i=1}^{n}{B_i} }
$$
Obviously these 2 values wont be the same except for very unique cases. However, from looking at these it seems to me that there must be some sort of statistical link between the 2 overall values.

I am by no means suggesting that there is a direct proportionality between the 2, however it appears that there may be some tenuous link up to a certain confidence level where you can say it is true that the 2 will differ by 'some factor' for a given variance or maybe it is something else that determines this 'factor'.

what I would be  interested in knowing is:

- If there is a link between the 2
- If so, then is it perhaps determined by the variance of the denominator, or the nominator, or both
- Does it depend on the type of distribution, or its support
- If there was a factor of sorts linking this, and what the confidence level might be.

I would be interested in seeing if there was a general rule similar to something like the [Rule Of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28statistics%29). I'd be extremely grateful if anyone could find something of this nature!

Ps. I couldn't find theory on this on the web, however if there is something like this out there then could you please link it below and I do realise this is an awful lot to consider, I'd be surprised to get an actual answer or validation on this in honesty.

Comment: Sorry you're totally right, I realise that it didn't make sense. Hopefully the edited version is clearer.

Comment: Much clearer. I've removed my comments.

Comment: I think this could be a quite difficult problem to study... For example, if you take mean zero and variance 1, for both $A$ and $B$, then the ratio $A_i/B_i$ is a standard Cauchy (so the average is also a standard Cauchy) and the ratio of sums is also Cauchy (I think). So even studying their correlation does not make sense...

Comment: Some useful insight could be gained in the case where the standard deviations are small with respect to the means by expanding with respect to $\Delta B_i=B_i-\bar B$ and calculating the means, variances and covariance of the two expressions up to second order.